# select custom UITableViewCell by Identifier from xib

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, identifier

I try to fill my UITableView withd different UITableViewCells. I tried to choose 1 of 3 UITableViewCells out of a XIB-file by identifier but I can't get the value of the UITableViewCell's Identifier.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)_tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{



MyTableViewCell *cell = (MyTableViewCell *) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CellTwo"];

 if(nil == cell){

  NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
  for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects) {
   if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[MyTableViewCell class]]) {
    MyTableViewCell *tmpCell = (MyTableViewCell *) currentObject;
    if (tmpCell.identifier == @"CellTwo") {
     cell = (MyTableViewCell *) currentObject;     
    }
    [tmpCell release];
    break;
   }
  } 
 }

 cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

 return cell;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this exact problem by creating a subclass for each UITableViewCell. When you do your comparison of the class type, you can put in the type of cell it is:

```
        cell = (FooterTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"footerTableViewCell"];

        if (cell == nil){

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CommonTableViewCell" owner:nil options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[FooterTableViewCell class]]){
                    cell = (FooterTableViewCell *)currentObject;
                    return cell;
                }
            }
        }
```

I have some tables that reuse the exact same kind of cell formatting and i wanted to have them in a common XIB that i can alter at anytime.  In the .h for that controller, i simply declared three sub classes of UITableViewCell for each of the three cell types.